# How to find the row that maximize a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, k-means

I have Three data frames : `london_working_hours`, `asian_london_table`,`london_table_earning` which have a column common who correspond to the borough name.

I would like to get the borough name which have the highest working value then get the population and the earning per hour of this borough

```
print("The highest borough in working hours , asian population and earning per hour is : ???")
```

this code gives me this result 
[image]
The last print should give me the Borough name which have the highest working hours with asian population and earning per hour how can I do that??

**Edit :**

You can find in the comment the link to my github for more details

Comment: hello can you give us a sample of your csv file ?

Comment: @OmarAldakar yes sure here is the link https://github.com/hazem-kamel/IBM-Business-Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this :

```
most_working_borough = london_working_hours.sort_values(by='Working Hours%', ascending=False).Boroughs.tolist()[0]
population = asian_london_table.loc[asian_london_table['Area'] == most_working_borough].Area.tolist()[0]
earning = london_table_earning.loc[london_table_earning['Area'] == most_working_borough].Area.tolist()[0]
```

Comment: yes this helps thank you so much , since you have background in machine learning too can you check my other question maybe you could help me also with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414217/k-means-clustering-concept

Comment: Ok I will have a look at it tonight.